Op Amp Feedback Resistors
When selecting feedback resistor values in operational amplifiers, how do you optimize the magnitude of the resistors? For example, I calculate the resistor 9/5 ratio value for a gain of 1.8
I know 5 and 9 Ohms are too low, causing high quiescent current; even 500 and 900 sound low but doable. Circuit simulators do not seem to care as I can make it 5M and 9M, which I think is too high, making the circuit vulnerable to transients. 5 and 9K sound reasonable, as do 50 and 90K.
How does one select the range? Efficiency is not a priority; stability is a priority because the circuit is a linear voltage regulator driving high current BJT. The op-amp used is an LT6016, if that helps.
Edit Note: Added circuit.


I think you could improve the answers you're getting if you show the exact circuit you're working with and the requirements. As said below, a basic trade-off of resistor is noise vs power consumption. One extreme, smaller resistors will have less noise but demand a lot of current from the amplifier (if it could feed them at all), and on the other you'll have little current demanded but a lot higher noise.

Thank you I added the circuit

To a first-order approximation, it's a matter of how much current the op-amp can provide (sets a lower bound on resistance), how much power you can stand to consume (sets a lower bound) how much error the op amp's input bias current (or, equivalently, its input impedance) would contribute (sets an upper bound), how much johnson-nyquist noise you can tolerate (sets an upper bound), and how noise-immune you need the feedback node to be (sets an upper bound).
In some cases, you may need to consider stability as well. If your resistors are too large and parasitic capacitances dominate the feedback network impedance, you may well end up making an oscillator instead of an amplifier!
Usually, values in the 1 kΩ to 1 MΩ range are reasonable, with values within that range chosen based on individual circuits' requirements. Rarely, there may be cause to go outside that range.

That all goes out the window when dealing with the less common current-feedback amplifiers, though. The key difference between a CFA and a conventional voltage-feedback op amp is, as the name implies, that the feedback is in the form of a current, not a voltage, and as such the inverting input has very low input impedance. This means your feedback network needs to allow enough current to flow into the inverting input, so the resistance needs to be low; it's common for CFA circuits to use feedback resistors in the 10 Ω to 1 kΩ range, usually closer to 100 Ω.

thank you. I added a portion of the circuit for review. I know it works because I have built a few prototypes and am working out any oversights for board fabrication.

There are a few considerations.

Frequency- at high frequency various capacitances have an effect so you don't generally want to be using MΩ resistors at high frequencies. It could cause poor behavior or instability. For example at 10MHz a 10pF capacitance has an impedance of only 1.6kΩ.

Power consumption and current capability- depending on the voltages involved, lower values use more current, which may exceed the output capability of the op-amp, may restrict the output range due to loading or may use excessive power (eg. battery situations).

Precision and noise- if you need high precision and/or low noise you generally don't want really high value resistors since a bit of leakage or input bias current can cause error. Higher value resistors also have proportionally more thermal noise which can be significant in some applications. If you need to operate at high temperatures, leakage will be worse so that points to lower values.

Standard values- if you want to minimize the number of resistors that have to be purchased and stocked, you probably want to make as many of the resistors as possible values like 10k, 20k, 100k, 4.99k etc. You an use that degree of freedom to get closer to a given ratio with standard values. Or use resistors in parallel and/or series to hit desired ratios more closely.


For most op-amps in the DC-50kHz range values in the 1kΩ to 100kΩ are reasonable. Maybe lower values if the input voltage are low (for example a gain of 100 amplifier would likely use some low value resistors). Much higher values may be practical for micropower circuits using CMOS op-amps and special situations such as photodiode transimpedance amplifiers or electrometer circuits and much lower values for extreme low noise amplifiers or RF.
These requirements generally result in a trade-off that is not optimal in any given part of the design solution.
For example, for 1.8 you could use 10.7kΩ/5.9kΩ (nominal error 0.75%), or 107kΩ/59kΩ.
The particular amplifier you mention is a so-called "over the top" amplifier, and if you are using that feature, the input bias current for CM voltages in that range is enormous compared to even a cheap jellybean amplifier (as much as 23uA), so (much) lower values are called for.
Here is a bit of a contrived example, using the higher value resistors I mentioned above:

The upper circuit uses your op-amp in the 'over the top' mode with an input signal of 100mV over the 10V bias. The ideal output voltage (with the given resistors) is 181.3mV below the 10V bias or about 9.819V. That is compared with an almost ideal OP177 operating with a +20V supply. As you can see, the error is many times (about 12x) the actual signal!
If we reduce the resistors by a couple orders of magnitude, the nominal output is now 10V - 0.1664V or "only" about 8% error. Adding a 380Ω resistor to the non-inverting input almost eliminates that error by balancing the offsets.


@Spehto thank you for taking the time to answer. You asked if an Over-the-Top opamp is required, and the answer is yes. I am not showing the current regulator; another LT6016 with high-side current sense. The non-inverter and inverting input operate at VCC, Resense = .01 Ohms. The op-amp is made to do what I am doing with it, high-precision regulators. Voltage regulation is better than .1%

So the lower value resistors are required for decent accuracy, as in the (balanced) 200Ω resistors shown in the datasheet example circuit. A special case, for sure. If you had a higher voltage supply just for the op-amp that put the inputs within the CM range then you could use (almost) any old op-amp that could handle the voltage, and much higher value resistors.

That is possible, and it crossed my mind. It would require a more expensive transformer with a higher voltage tap, its rectifiers, filters, and regulator. Added expense, unnecessary, and more hardware to fail hardware to fail. Several Op Amps are explicitly made for this application. My problem is op-amp design is not my specialty; it is more of a hobby than anything else. I appreciate the help.

@Dereck This is all true. Of course if you are making something inexpensive in high volume, the LT6016 may be considered ludicrously expensive and to present a business risk as being single-sourced compared to a few cheap and ultimately very reliable jellybean parts. Horses for courses.

Introduction
Both non-inverting and inverting op-amp amplifiers use the same voltage divider as a feedback network; only in the former, it is an ordinary 1-input device while in the latter, it is a 2-input device (aka "resistor summing circuit" or simply, "resistor summer"). So both devices consist of two resistors (R1 and R2) in series supplied by the op-amp output VOA (in non-inverting circuits) or by the difference Vin - VOA between the input Vin and op-amp output VOA voltages (in inverting circuits). Their outputs are connected to the non-inverting and inverting inputs, respectively, which are loads for them. Unwanted leakages and capacitances are also added to these.
What is important for these two devices is the ratio between the resistance values and not the values themselves. Therefore, as the OP notes in their question, this ratio is satisfied for different pairs of resistance values, and it should be clarified which one to take. The considerations for their selection are generally valid; op-amp circuits are only specific applications.
Voltage divider feedback
For example, we can represent a 10x op-amp non-inverting amplifier by the conceptual circuit below where:

The voltage source VOA represents the op-amp output
The voltage divider R1-R2 is the feedback network
I shows the current flowing through the voltage divider (R1)
R+ is the input resistance of the op-amp non-inverting input (assuming it is 1 MΩ)
V+ is the voltage at the op-amp non-inverting input

Let's examine the circuit at three different resistance values keeping the same ratio R2/(R1 + R2) = 1/10, and sweep R+ from 1 kΩ to 1 MΩ.
Low-resistance divider: R1 = 900 Ω, R2 = 100 Ω: First, we note that the 10 mA current can be too much for an ordinary op-amp.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As we can see from the graph below, the influence of R+ is negligible because the low-resistance divider behaves as a "stiff" voltage source.

Moderate-resistance divider: R1 = 90 kΩ, R2 = 10 kΩ

simulate this circuit
Now the impact of R+ is greater...

High-resistance divider: R1 = 900 kΩ, R2 = 100 kΩ

simulate this circuit
... and when the divider has a very high resistance, the effect of R+ is greatest.

Voltage summer feedback
Similarly, we can represent a -10x op-amp inverting amplifier with high-resistance resistors (R1 = 100 kΩ, R2 = 1 MΩ) by the conceptual circuit below. To observe the currents flowing through R1 and R2, we can represent the resistors by real ammeters with the same resistance.
Now let's examine the circuit at various loads.
Open circuit (no load): If we apply 1 V input voltage, the op-amp output voltage is -10 V and the voltage between the two resistors (at the inverting input) is zero (the so-called "virtual ground").

simulate this circuit
Negative leakage Rleak = 1 MΩ (to V-): Because the resistor summer has a high resistance, if a parasitic leakage path connects the inverting input with a -10 V voltage source, -833 mV appears.

simulate this circuit
Positive leakage Rleak = 1 MΩ (to V+): If the leakage path connects the inverting input with a 10 V voltage source, 833 mV appears.

simulate this circuit
Exiting bias current Ib = 1 μA: To simulate an exiting op-amp input bias current, we can connect a 1 μA current source between the ground and the common point between resistors. It "creates" a 90 mV undesired voltage drop across the divider output resistance.

simulate this circuit
Entering bias current Ib = 1 μA: To simulate an entering input bias current, we can connect a 1 μA current sink to the common point between resistors. Now it "creates" a -90 mV undesired voltage drop across the divider output resistance.

simulate this circuit
Understanding OP's circuit
The OP's circuit is an unusual circuit design that deserves closer examination. The best way to do it is by following its evolution step by step.
5 V voltage regulator
The simplest voltage regulator consists of a powerful voltage source VL that follows a low-power reference voltage source VZ (i.e., a voltage follower with a constant input voltage). This way, a constant voltage can be maintained even across a low-resistance load RL.
Referenced to ground: Typically, both voltage sources are grounded. We can simulate this arrangement by manually adjusting the voltage VL of the copying source to match the reference voltage VZ. To achieve this, we can connect a null-indicator NI (sensitive voltmeter) between the two sources and null the voltage across it. This arrangement is known as a negative feedback system.

simulate this circuit
Referenced to V1: In the OP's circuit, for a reason yet to be explained, it has proven more convenient to connect both 5 V voltage sources to the positive terminal of the 17 V supply V1.

simulate this circuit
Buffered 5 V regulator
We can create a high-power 5 V  regulator by buffering a low-power source with a powerful transistor (FET, BJT, etc.) In the OP's circuit, a common-source stage is used for this purpose. It is implemented by an N-channel MOSFET. The load is connected between the drain and B1. Ah, that is why the voltage sources in the above schematic 3.2 are connected to V1!

simulate this circuit
It is worth noting that to overcome the transistor's threshold voltage, we are required to increase VOA by 4V.
Buffered 14 V regulator
But judging by the OP's schematic, we need not 5 V, but 14 V. So, something must force us to set a VL voltage that is 14/5 times higher than VZ.
Man-controlled conceptual circuit: The trick is simple: by comparing 5/14 of the output voltage with the input, we are forced to increase it by a factor of 14/5 relative to the input. The attenuation is made by an Rd1-Rd2 voltage divider (Rd1 is implemented by a 5 kΩ voltmeter to visualize the voltage drop across it).

simulate this circuit
VCVS conceptual circuit: We can assign a VCVS (with a gain of 300 k) to do this...

simulate this circuit
Op-amp implementation: ... and then an op-amp with the same gain. The circuit actually represents a buffered op-amp non-inverting amplifier. Note, however, that the op-amp inputs are swapped compared to the unbuffered circuit. This is because the common-source stage inverts the signal.

simulate this circuit

The circuit is unique for a good reason: heat management. What is not apparent is that I can ground the negative output terminal to the chassis. That means I do not need any electrical isolators blocking heat transfer to the pass transistor. Also, it is not apparent that the circuit is intended to drive multiple NPN pass transistors. No electrical isolators are needed; the collectors are grounded.

@Dereck, I must admit, it's hard for me to visualize your whole system without a diagram, but I trust that you're correct.
